# Dual-boot Debian Squeeze and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, grub, debian-squeeze

I had Windows 7 on my system, after which I installed Debian Squeeze. However, `grub` doesn't show my Windows 7 in the boot menu.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Ubuntu 8.04 and then installed Debian 6.0. I did not have to configure the menu list - it just went right the first time.

After a few days I saw the menu item for Ubuntu was not present on the boot screen. Following some research on the net I found a good command that solved my problem:

Open a root terminal and type:

```
update-grub
```

This command is a utility provided by Debian to automatically generate the `grub.cfg` file that detects the file systems and adds menu entries accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have package **os-prober** installed. It should be able to recognize Windows automatically.

It's very inconvenient to configure it on hand every time grub or kernel packages are updated.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer doesn't work. Debian 6 uses Grub 2, not Grub 1, so there is no `menu.lst` anymore, this is replaced by `grub.cfg` file.

The file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` is wrong in Debian 6. My solution was to grab this file from an Ubuntu 10.04 installation. I just replaced it and after that ran update-grub (could also be grub-update, typing this in Win XP...) as root. After that a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` was created and I could boot both Windows 7 and Debian 6!

Answer (score 0):

put

```
title Windows 7
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1
```

in /boot/grub/menu.lst
(I am asuming you are using first partition for Windows)